# Is there any benefit to "small mode" in Super Mario Kart?

Tags: super-mario-kart

In Super Mario Kart, you are able to start each race of the the GP mode small, as though you had been hit by lightning if you hold `Y` and then Press `A`.  You are able to become regular size if you collect the thrown mushrooms during the course of the race.

Is there any benefit to playing this way?  As far as I can tell, the only difference is that the AI character that usually is in second place will throw mushrooms that you can use to become regular size and that that is the only item available to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are not really any benefits to being small in Super Mario Kart. The idea behind the lightning bolt is to slow other drivers down. You can also become small when you hit a poison mushroom from Toad or Princess Toadstool (Peach). Hitting a poison mushroom or being hit with a lightning bolt while small will reverse the effects and make you big again.

Running over small drivers also causes them to lose time driving and therefore can cause them to be placed further back into the race.

Comment: I understand that, in general, small mode is detrimental.  I'm talking about activating small mode from the character select with `Y` and `A` like adding a marking to GP results noting that you went through the whole thing in small mode.

Comment: This has no benefit. it's more so just a challenge you can set for yourself and allow your opponents to run you over. Beating the game in this mode will not do anything special.